# How do I run a doctest from Cython?

Tags: python, c, cython, doctest

## The Setup

1. Let's say I have a script `fib.py`. With some doctests in it.

   ```py
   def fib(n):
       """Return the nth number in the Fibonacci sequence.

       >>> fib(0)
       0.0
       >>> fib(1)
       1.0
       >>> fib(4)
       3.0
       >>> fib(7)
       13.0
       """
       a, b = 0.0, 1.0
       for i in range(n):
           a, b = a + b, a
       return a

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       import doctest
       doctest.testmod()
   ```

   Everything works as expected and I can confirm that the tests are running 
   by checking the output of `python3 fib.py -v`.
2. Alright, now I'm going to translate this into Cython, and for good measure I'll even remove
   the `if __name__ == '__main__'` conditional.
   Let's call our Cython file `fib.pyx`

   ```
   #cython: language_level=3

   def fib(int n):
       """Return the nth number in the Fibonacci sequence.

       >>> fib(0)
       0.0
       >>> fib(1)
       1.0
       >>> fib(4)
       3.0
       >>> fib(7)
       13.0
       """
       cdef int i
       cdef double a=0.0, b=1.0
       for i in range(n):
           a, b = a + b, a
       return a

   import doctest
   doctest.testmod()
   ```
3. Of course we need to compile our Cython. For me that's

   ```sh
   cython --embed fib.pyx
   gcc $(python-config --cflags) $(python-config --ldflags) fib.c
   ```

   This produces `a.out`.
4. If I try `./a.out -v` I get . . .

   ```sh
   1 items had no tests:
       __main__
   0 tests in 1 items.
   0 passed and 0 failed.
   Test passed.
   ```

**What happened to my tests?**

## (Potentially) helpful links.

- [Python Docs: doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html)
- [Cython FAQ: doctests](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-run-doctests-in-cython-code-pyx-files)
- [Cython Docs: Using C libraries (testing the result)](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html#testing-the-result)

Comment: Could you rely on `pytest` for running the doctests?

Comment: Sure as long as the doctests run. I tried installing it via `pip install pytest && pip install pytest-cython`. According to the help page I can run `pytest --doctest-cython` to run all doctests, but it says there are 0 tests to run.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, there were a few problems here . . .

First I wasn't really compiling properly. The final result should be a `.so` file on MacOs/Linux systems and a `.pyd` file on linux.

#### Building a Cython module

You can quickly compile by writing a `setup.py` file

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize('fib.pyx'))
```

Depending on your OS and python version running

```py
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

will produce something like `fib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

For more info see the relevant [Cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-setuptools).

#### Install pytest modules

```sh
pip install pytest
pip install pytest-cython
```

- [PyPi: pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/)
- [PyPi: pytest-cython](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cython/)

#### Running the tests

From the directory where your compiled Cython lives run . . .

```py
pytest --doctest-cython -v
```

The `-v` is of course `verbose` and provides additional output.

From `pytest --help | grep cython` we can see what this command is doing.

```sh
cython:
  --doctest-cython      run doctests in all .so and .pyd modules
  --cython-ignore-import-errors
```